# does AzCopy have an exit code which can be used to throw error in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azcopy

Like Robocopy (http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) does Azcopy have an exit code. If not what would be the best way to throw error for Azcopy when transfer was not successful inside a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit code 0 means transferring succeeded, other exit codes means different kinds of error in AzCopy. Currently we haven't officially announced meaning of all error codes.

Comment: Is there by any chance any documentation now about the error codes?

Comment: I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1507) requesting those exit codes to be documented