# AzCopy - what are return values?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I use AzCopy in a .CMD batch file and I need to know when it exited successfully or errored out. Specifically, when the transfer is interrupted I need to restart the command.

What are exit codes for AzCopy?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746054/does-azcopy-have-an-exit-code-which-can-be-used-to-throw-error-in-a-powershell-s

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. That question was asked THREE YEARS ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it's not implemented yet but hopefully some day. Track this issue - https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/289

Answer (score 0):

For [Azcopy V10](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy)(latest),  **AzCopy will print UPLOADFAILED, COPYFAILED, and DOWNLOADFAILED** strings for failures with the paths along with the error reason. You can find more details in the provided link within Github.

Comment: That's close! But if I use AzCopy in a .cmd file I need a return value to evaluate the results. And if there were failures I want to restart the operation automatically. Those UPLOADFAILED, etc strings are put into log. Not sure I could parse the log in a simple .CMD file.

I do see this version has automatic retries. Maybe that's what I need, not sure.