# Azcopy upload then delete local

Tags: powershell, azcopy

I'm working on a Powershell script to upload files to an Azure blob from a local directory then if successful remove the local files. The blob is just a staging location and the files are moved from there so I cannot sync. I think the only way to do this might be to check the status of the copy from the log? I thought this may do what I need but it just starts uploading all the files again when it cycles back through and never continues and removes the source. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
while($true){
    .\azcopy copy "$Upload\*.iso" (SAS URL) --log-level ERROR
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 -Verbose
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AzCopy - what are return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299246/azcopy-what-are-return-values)

Comment: Not quite. I could use the return values to have it loop back if the transfer was unsuccessful, but it appears it will upload all files again if I do this. This may be because the destination files are being removed after I upload them. I need to be able to check to see if each file was successful and if so delete, if not try again. I think this may be possible from the session logs, just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's link got me going in the right direction.

```
    .\azcopy copy "$Upload\*.iso" "SAS" --log-level ERROR
    IF ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0){
    Write-Host "Transfer Successful"
    Write-Host "Remove files after Azure copy is done"
    rm "Source" -Verbose
    Stop-Transcript
    }
    IF ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
    Write-Host "Transfer Failed"
    Stop-Transcript
    }
```